# Root/non-root user permissions to edit file

Tags: shell-script, permissions, root

I am running scriptA.sh as root. Inside the script I need to echo data into FileA. FileA is owned by user1. FileA is located under /usr/local and has the following permissions:

```
-rw-r----- 1 user1 group
```

FileA permissions cannot be modified. Right now, when I run scriptA I get permission denied on FileA. Is there anyway to get around this inside the script?

Psuedo code from scriptA that writes to FileA:

```
function update_FileA()
   {
      if [ condition ] then
         echo "XYZ data" >> FileA
         else
         echo "ABC data" >> FileA
      fi   
   }
```

**Update:** Tried a few things. I tried to vi FileA as user1 and as root and I was able to successfully edit. Its only when trying to edit the file through the script write access is denied.

Comment: `echo foo | sudo -u user1 tee FileA`, perhaps. How exactly are you executing the script and how exactly are you echoing data to the file?

Comment: Root has permission to read all files,  can you show the contents of scriptA.sh

Comment: @muru, tried ur suggestion, still seeing permission denied. I am logged in as root and then script is executed from the terminal-> ./scriptA.sh

Comment: @Arushix, added psuedo code to the OP.

Comment: Your code works for me, make sure your script does not have setuid or setgit bit set, can you show the permissions and ownership of your script as well

Comment: @Arushix script perms - rwxrwxrwx

Comment: Is the target data file on a remote or otherwise nonstandard filesystem?

Comment: @roaima, target file is not remote and is on a standard filesystem

Comment: Then it's an selinux issue.

Comment: Or perhaps the file has the "immutable" attribute set? (check with the lsattr command) Or maybe the system has detected some filesystem corruption and switched to read-only mode?